# Rails server not running when using Rails gem version 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, railstutorial.org

I have created a new Rails project. And used the gem file used in the famous Michael Hartl tutorial

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
   gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
   group :development, :test do
   gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
   gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

When running rails server am received this error message:

> could not find gem rails in the gems available on the machine
>   run bundle install..

I know am running on rails 3.2.9 I have checked with the command rails -v
what is going wrong? Am using Windows 7 - 64 bits. am a ruby on rails newbie.
When I change to gem rails 3.2.8 no more errors appear and rails server run successfully.

Further errors I remember getting through my trials of adding gems and running bundle install bundle update..etc

when i run bundle install as suggested by the '`console`', many different errors start to appear! first:

> em::Package::FormatError: no metadata found in..../activerecord -3.2.9
>   and bundler cannot continue.
>   make sure that gem install activerecord -v '3.2.9' succeeds before bundling

Then I have tried to add the gem to my gem file and run bundle install again and then I got error asking for activesupport gem. I  have added that to the gem and run bundle install again, tried with bundle update .. keep getting erros, also asking for railties gem...etc

Comment: try installing 3.2.9 manually before including it in you GEMFILE,  gem install rails -v ">=3.2.9"

Comment: I have uninstalled RailsInstaller and reinstalled the latest version again. I have created a new project with the command rails new app-name. when bundle install runs am getting the error :
    gem::package::FormatError: no metadata found in 
D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/cashe/activereocrd-3.2.9.gem
and error occurrend while installing activerecord (3.2.9), and bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install activerecord -v '3.2.9' succeeds before building.
Even after running gem install ... and running bundle install again, am getting same error.

Comment: As tried before when I change the gem file to rails v 3.2.8 everything works as normal.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle exec rails console` should just give you a console, if you ran `bundle` in the rails root directory.

Comment: I guess you mean `bundle exec rails console`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is something went wrong with the installation of the rails gem. Uninstall rails (version 2.3.9) and install again (run `bundle`). Or if you use rvm, start in a clean gemset.

Comment: tried to uninstall rails with the command gem uninstall rails and removed both versions available in my installation which is 3.2.1 and 3.2.9. then run bundle install and problems still happening.
tried to uninstall rails gems again, and run bundle install but only after removing the gem rails line from the gem file as advised by @Antarr Byrd , then run bundle install. now when running rails -v am getting versoin 3.2.8 instead of 3.2.9?? why is that? anyway although it is rails 2.3.8 when i run rails s, am getting errors regarding undefined method 'active_record'! Am lost.

Answer (score 0):

uninstalled Railsinstaller and related leftovers folders.
reinstalled Railsinstaller and problem solved.